# best way to store an array in database and getting it back as array from database

Tags: php, html, sql, arrays, mysqli

So I have these html inputs that I can regenerate them with javascript to allow user to enter his experience history, so lets assume this code is generated twice like this

```
<!-- User Experiense 1 -->
<label>Company Name</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="company_name[]">

<label for="job-title">Job Title</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="job_title[]">

<label for="dates">From</label>
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="start_date[]">

<label for="dates">To</label>
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="end_date[]">

<!-- User Experiense 2 -->
<label>Company Name</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="company_name[]">

<label for="job-title">Job Title</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="job_title[]">

<label for="dates">From</label>
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="start_date[]">

<label for="dates">To</label>
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="end_date[]">
```

and these are the columns in database `company_name` `job_title` `start_date` `end_date`

and here is the php code

```
$js_company_name = [];
if(isset($_POST['js_company_name'])){   
   foreach($_POST['js_company_name'] as $selected) {
     $js_company_name[] = $selected ;
  }
}

$js_job_title = [];
if(isset($_POST['job_title'])){
   foreach($_POST['job_title'] as $selected) {
      $job_title[] = $selected;
   }
 }

$start_date= [];
if(isset($_POST['start_date'])){
   foreach($_POST['start_date'] as $selected) {
      $start_date[] = $selected;
   }
 }

$end_date= [];
if(isset($_POST['end_date'])){
   foreach($_POST['end_date'] as $selected) {
      $end_date[] = $selected;
   }
 }
```

I tried to use `serialize()` and `unserialize()` functions but I thik its not the best solution and it cases a lot of errors espicially for huge data.
So I was hoping if there is a better solution to store array in database,
thanks in advance :)

Comment: try to store data in `json` formate in database

Comment: how is that please :)

Comment: nosql: https://www.mongodb.com/

Comment: in my humble opinion you should INSERT every experince into a different row, in the future you can easily report, search , gather or group by them etc

Comment: try `json_encode()` and `json_decode()` function

Comment: I will put your solution for consideration , if I couldn't find a better solution I will use yours, thanks @Santa'shelper

Comment: I think `json_encode()` has the same problem with `serialize()` ,thanks for your answer @NikhilVaghla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply should not. This not only violates the [First normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) of relational database design, but you may also fall victim to alignment error when all that connects what should be your "Experience" entity is the array index counter.

E.g.: If not all fields are mandatory, does an empty form entry create an empty array value? That might depend on the client (browser) that submits the form.

In any case it's bad database design and you should really consider modelling this concept as UserExperience or similar and connect it Many-To-One to the user.

Comment: So you are suggesting to create another table in database for user experience? @YetiCGB

Comment: Exactly. Also take a look at [3NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form) and relational database modelling principles.

Comment: I think this will be the only solution , I just didn't want to separate user data in multiple tables ,because user experience isn't the only data that I need to store in this way , there is education too!, so in this solution there will be at least 3 tables for user data @YetiCGN

Comment: Don't be afraid of more tables and having to use JOIN a lot! That *is* the correct way to do it. :-)

Comment: Thanks my friend :)